# node oracle all or nothing query

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am currently using `nodeJS Oracle library` to make queries to remote database.

However, it seems that the library is only able to process single query at a time.

So for example `CREATE TABLE test1 (example1 Number, example2 Number)` and another query `CREATE TABLE test2 (example1 Number, example2 Number)` works separately but when I try to do

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (example1 Number, example2 Number)
CREATE TABLE test2 (example1 Number, example2 Number)
```

all in one go as shown below, it throws `Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`

```
regular:function (oracledb, connectionConfig, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    /*
    * successHandler : function(result){}
    * errorHandler : function(error){}
    * */

    let userId = connectionConfig.userId;
    let password = connectionConfig.password;
    let host = connectionConfig.ip;
    let port = connectionConfig.port;
    let sid = connectionConfig.sid;
    let query = 'CREATE TABLE test1 (example1 Number, example2 Number)
CREATE TABLE test2 (example1 Number, example2 Number)'

    oracledb.getConnection(
        {
            user          : userId,
            password      : password,
            connectString : `(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ${host})(PORT = ${port}))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ${sid})))`
        },
        function(err, connection)
        {
            if (err) {
                errorHandler(err);
                return;
            }
            connection.execute(
                query,
                function(err, result)
                {
                    if (err) {
                        errorHandler(err);
                        oracleFunctions.connection.doRelease(connection, errorHandler);
                        return;
                    }

                    successHandler(result);
                    oracleFunctions.connection.doRelease(connection, errorHandler);
                });
        });
},
```

FYI the queries work on `DataGrip`. Is there a way to make sure that multiple tables are created only when all of them are successfullly created but fails all together if any of the queries are unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SQL*Plus or SQLcl to execute the script. Keep in mind you will need to terminate your statements with semicolons:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (example1 Number, example2 Number);
CREATE TABLE test2 (example1 Number, example2 Number);
```

or forward slashes (depending on what you're doing):

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (example1 Number, example2 Number)
/
CREATE TABLE test2 (example1 Number, example2 Number)
/
```

In this case, you could use one or the other, but not both.

Here's an example of the script you have working in Node.js:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js'); 
let conn;

async function multipleDDL() {
  try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    let result;

    result = await conn.execute('create table t1 (c1 number, c2 number)');

    result = await conn.execute('create table t2 (c1 number, c2 number)');

    console.log('tables created successfully');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

multipleDDL();
```

And here's how that could be rewritten to use a PL/SQL block with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to issue the statements:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js'); 
let conn;

async function multipleDDL() {
  try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    let result;

    result = await conn.execute(
     `begin
        execute immediate 'create table t1 (c1 number, c2 number)';
        execute immediate 'create table t2 (c1 number, c2 number)';
      end;`
    );

    console.log('tables created successfully');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

multipleDDL();
```

I believe there may be a way to avoid the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but I'll have to look into it (not sure how easy the solution is).

As to the script succeeding or failing all together, this is a tricky problem because in Oracle, DDL issues implicit commits. Different people use different approaches depending on the situation. Here are two options:

1. You could write your own "back out" scripts and execute those if something goes wrong.
2. A colleague of mine suggested that if you have sole control of the database, you could do the following

   create restore point X;

   // do DDL

   // something breaks

   flashback database to restore point X;

Comment: Very nice solution thanks. but as to 2 I cannot perform it. If the second execute immediate fails the first would still proceed right? - which isn't really what I was looking for but the fact that the tables can be created with single connection may suffice for now. Please do let me know if you do find any alternative solutions. Thanks

Comment: I see. The title of the question is "node oracle all or nothing query", but it's probably more accurate to say "Oracle all or nothing DDL". The reason is that SQL is often broken down into DML and DDL. In Oracle, DML can be transactional, but DDL issues implicit commits (before and after it executes). That's why one would have to write "back out" scripts. Another colleague suggests looking into something like Liquibase or FLyway which can help generate the DDL to go in either direction. Backout DML would still be your responsibility.